# Where can I find the meaning of flags in Linux (-rf, -h, -r, -R, -l, etc.)

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, ubuntu

I am super new to Linux and Bash scripting.

Is there a website where I have an overview for all the different flags and operators?

the Bash scripting cheatsheet is missing quite a few.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `man application_name` or in rare cases `info application_name`

Comment: it has nothing to do with Bash or with shell scripts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each command has its own set of options, and the documentation will be (should be) on your own system. For example, `man ls` to read about the `ls` command, and `man ps` to read about `ps`.

Comment: Also, many commands provide their own usage instructions when called with `--help`, e.g. `ls --help`.

Comment: Thank you very much!